# How to use same category id with multiple columns in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have jobseekers table and job titles table,
in job titles table

```html
id job_title_key description
1   001              sales 
2   002              programmer
```

and in job seeker table

```html
id jobseeker_name desire_position_1 desire_position_2
1   Sam               001                        002
2   Smith             002                        002
```

when i query to filter using scope

```html
public function scopeSearch($query, $request) { 
    if($request->desire_position_1 != '') {
        $query->join('job_titles','jobseekers.desire_position_1','=','job_titles.job_title_key');
      }  

      if($request->desire_position_2!='') {
          $query->join('job_titles','jobseekers.desire_position_2','=','job_titles.job_title_key');
      }  
      
    if ($request->desire_position_1!='') {
        $exp_2 = explode(',', $request->desire_position_1);    
        $query->where('job_titles.description',$exp_2);
    }

    if ($request->desire_position_2!='') {
        $exp_3= explode(',', $request->desire_position_2);    
        $query->where('job_titles.description',$exp_3);
    }
}
```

its showing the error like the following photo,[image]

anyone have an idea for this solution?

Comment: What do you want as the final result of the query? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issued with this following query,

```html
  public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
    { 
    if($request->desire_position_1!=''){
        $query->join('job_titles','jobseekers.desire_position_1','=','job_titles.job_title_key');
      }  
      if($request->desire_position_2!=''){
          $query->join('job_titles as job_titles_ds2','jobseekers.desire_position_2','=','job_titles.job_title_key');
      }  
      
       if ($request->desire_position_1!='') {
        $exp_2 = explode(',', $request->desire_position_1);    
       $query->where('job_titles.description',$exp_2);
      }    
      if ($request->desire_position_2!='') {
        $exp_3= explode(',', $request->desire_position_2);    
      $query->where('job_titles_ds2.description',$exp_3);
      }    
      return $query->select('jobseekers.*'); 
      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the table two times with the same alias: `$query->join('job_titles', ...)`.

Use different aliases and it should work.

Comment: ya, how to use different alias, i want to use the same job titles with that desire position 1 and 2 .i dont want to seperate table either.